# How to remove perforce (p4) on Ubuntu

Tags: perforce, ubuntu-18.04

I had perforce `p4` installed on my Ubuntu 18.4. I broke it using the following sequence of mistakes!

```
sudo apt-get remove helix-p4d
sudo apt-get purge helix-p4d
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm /etc/perforce
sudo rm /opt/perforce
```

Then I installed it again using

```
sudo apt-get install helix-p4d
```

However, after installation it genereates the following error:

> p4dctl error:     fopen: /etc/perforce/p4dctl.conf: No such file or
>   directory

My question is, how can I completely remove `p4` and all of its services and reinstall everything from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also do:

```
sudo apt-get remove helix-p4dctl
sudo apt-get purge helix-p4dctl
```

This will fix the problem with that missing file/directory and you can install again.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, I basically removed and purged all helix components:

```
sudo apt remove helix*
sudo apt purge helix*
sudo rm -rf /etc/perforce
sudo rm -rf /opt/perforce
```

On my system I also had to delete a service named "helix-p4dctl.service", but i'm not sure if that always is na issue after everything is purged.